# Help understanding the C stdarg macros (va_start ...)

Tags: c, variadic-functions

recently i came across this function (used in a logger class). I understand **what** it does, but i do not know **how**:

```
void Reporter::print( const char* szFormat, ...)
{
    // note: m_out is a FILE*
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, szFormat);
    vfprintf( m_out, szFormat, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

I read the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/), but still it's unclear to me. What is bugging me the most is that this doesn't work as expected. I get 0 for the last number and (null) for the string, although it should print some number greater than 0 and a path to a file.

**Case 1:**

```
rep.print( "Values: %08X %08X %08X %08X %08X %08X %d %s\n", val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, source.GetLength(), szPath );
// source.GetLength() returns a size_t, szPath is a const char* and IS indeed a valid string
```

But changing it to this works fine:

**Case 2:**

```
rep.print( "Values: %08X %08X %08X %08X %08X %08X", val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 );
rep.print( " %d %s\n", source.GetLength(), szPath );
```

Note that i'm compiling under MSVC++ 2008. The same code works fine (even the first case) under gcc. Is there a bug in the implementation of Reporter::print() or in the way I use the function? How can I make sure that it will work fine even when called as in the first case? And why does it even fail?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's a bug in MSVC.

Comment: What types are all the val variables?

Comment: All of them are `unsigned long`'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for `Reporter::print` is fine.  All it is doing is correctly initialising `args` to refer to the variable argument list, then passing that variable argument list on to `vfprintf()`, which knows what to do with it.

Your problem is likely that the `%d` format specifier (which requires an `int` type argument) does not match the type of the value returned by `source.GetLength()` (which I would hazard a guess is possibly a `size_t`).  If you know the length will always fit into an `int`, then you can solve it with a cast conversion:

```
..., (int)source.GetLength(), ...
```

(this is so because the expected type of the arguments that are part of the variable argument list are not known to the compiler, unlike a normal prototype function declaration).

Comment: It is a size_t (mentioned in my question). Unfortunatelly, this didn't help. I'm actually experiencing crashes (access violation in MS runtime library (msvcr90d.dll)). Everything works fine when `case 2` code is used. Really strange. (and i'm runing it on a LOT of files, so i hope this is not just plain luck that it works).

Comment: Ok sorry, i was wrong (messed up the format string while debugging ... fast edits, oh boy). This was really the case - `size_t` somehow messed with the function or whatever. Casting to `int` resolved the issue. Thanks!